# I want to get value of an attribute from an XML file

Tags: xml, c#-2.0

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books>
    <Book id="1">
        <Author>Mark</Author>
        <Publisher>Sams</Publisher>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

This is the code to extract the attribute:

```
 XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("D:\\books.xml");
            textReader.MoveToElement();
            string au = textReader.GetAttribute("Auther");
            Uname.Text = au;
```

Comment: to be more precise: what do you want to do and what does not work?

Comment: And is that a typo? Auther vs. Author?

Comment: "id" on the `<book>` tag is an attribute - but "author" (check your SPELLING!) is an element

Answer (score 3):

Author is not an Attribute, it is an Element of the Element Book.

I think you need some basics of XML first, before you start parsing it.

e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/

What might help also is looking into XPath. It helps you in selecting Elements. This is helpful especially if you already know the structure of the XML you'd like to parse.